# If a 4x4 matrix A is diagonalizable, is A+4I diagonalizable as well?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

The matrix $I$ is the $4 \times 4$ identity matrix.

If this is true, how do I show that? If it's false, how would I find a counterexample?

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:**
$$
P(D + 4I)P^{-1} = PDP^{-1} + 4I
$$